# Could not start Windows Service, Error 1064

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, windows-10

I wrote a Windows Service to run on Win10, and it worked perfectly fine until I decided to change it a bit. I rewrote some logic, tested it in both Debug and Release configurations, and everything was fine. Then, I uninstalled the current version of the service using `installutil.exe /u %servicename.exe%` and reinstalled it again using `installutil.exe %servicename.exe%`.

For some reason, this new version cannot start, and it crashes with **Error 1064**. This is the full error text:

> Windows could not start %servicename% service on Local Computer. Error 1064: An exception occurred in the service when handling the control request.

The last time I installed this service, I ran into some difficulties, but quickly fixed them by changing the `Log On` properties. This time, it is not working. Please help with this issue.

**Update 1**

Here are my `Main()` and `OnStart()` service methods:

`Main()`

```
static void Main()
{
#if DEBUG
    var service = new SalesforceToJiraService();
    service.OnDebug();
    Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
#else
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
    {
        new SalesforceToJiraService()
    };
     ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#endif
}
```

`OnStart()`

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    this.ConfigureServices();

    this.timer.Start();
    this.logger.Information("SalesforceToJira service started.");
}
```

**Update 2**

More code:

`ConfigureServices()`

```
protected void ConfigureServices()
{
    this.configuration = ConfigurationHelper.LoadConfiguration(ConfigurationPath);
    this.logger = ConfigurationHelper.ConfigureLogger(this.configuration.Logs.LogsPath);

    this.timer = ConfigurationHelper.ConfigureTimer(this.configuration.ProcessInterval.TotalMilliseconds,
        (sender, eventArgs) => this.ProcessCasesAsync(sender, eventArgs).GetAwaiter().GetResult());

    this.salesforceClient = new SalesforceCliClient(this.configuration.Salesforce.CliPath);

    this.jiraClient = Jira.CreateRestClient(
        this.configuration.Jira.Url,
        this.configuration.Jira.Username,
        this.configuration.Jira.Password);
}
```

I'm using `Newtonsoft.JSON` for deserializing a JSON configuration file, `Serilog` for logging, `System.Timers.Timer` for periodic events, `AtlassianSDK` for the Jira API and some wrappers over `Salesforce CLI` for Salesforce.

Comment: Sounds like you did something wrong. Since you won't show us the code you'll [have to learn how to debug](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Comment: I run it in Release configuration, it worked fine, I did not changed Installer class so I cannot see a reason why it cannot start.

Comment: Your code appears incomplete. What happens if you comment out     `this.ConfigureServices();` and `this.timer.Start();`?

Comment: More detailed error messages will appear in the Event Viewer. Look there for the exact reason why the service failed.

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex: This was a very good suggestion for me, the root cause (faulty configuration) was given in the initial event of the event cascade.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Thanks to [@Siderite Zackwehdex's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365517/could-not-start-windows-service-error-1064#comment93607863_53365517), I was able to find the full stack trace of the underlying exception in Event Viewer, under:

> Windows Logs\Application

In my case, my service is named `HttpDispatcher`, which appears in the **"Source"** column in the top pane.

I could see immediately it was due to a dependency issue where my .NET 4.7.2 project was not pulling across my .NET Standard references.  ([That ol' chestnut](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReferencingNETStandardAssembliesFromBothNETCoreAndNETFramework.aspx)).

[image: Event Viewer: Windows Logs/Application]

Comment: Though i see a lot of answers talking about the specific issues they faced which caused this issue, this is the only post talking about how to figure out the issue :)

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue. The reason was I forgot to set the Database connection properly in configurations.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same error 1064 starting my service. For me the user I had the service registered as was not a valid user in the database. Once added, it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same error in my Windows Service.
The reason was it can't read a configuration parameter, so it crash.

Adding some validation (bugfixing), the Windows Services can start it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error was due to issues with Event log name

It got fixed after I went to **RegEdit** and deleted old service name from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue. In my case it is due to connection fail with the data base. I think it is due to code throw the exception.

My error :
Windows could not start the service1 service on local computer.

**Error 1064**: An exception occured in the service when handling the control request

I corrected my issue by updating the third party DLL.

Comment: Please respond only with answers. If you have a new question, please post another post and refer to this one in that.

Answer (score 0):

**I faced the same issue, here is how I resolved it after troubleshooting.**

- If you are running service on the Server with multiple users, make
  sure to run the service as admin user. Click on the service
  properties and then on Log on tab click on this account and provide
  the admin user name and password.
- And If your service is accessing    some shared drive, then make sure
  you have a general user on all    servers for accessing the shared
  drives and add the user as local    admin as well.

Answer (score 0):

For me it happened when I tried to restart a process. Turned out the process was  hanging in 'Stopping' so I had to kill it manually via command line and the PID.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using .net 7.0 then you need to add Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices.dll
and  .UseWindowsService() in program.cs file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).